# Additional arguments to "connectionArgs" Relay js

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

For example I have connection type:

```
let usersType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Users',
    description: 'users array',
    fields: () => ({
        array: {
            type: userConnection,
            description: 'all users',
            args: connectionArgs,
            searchFor: {
                type: GraphQLString
            },
            resolve: (root, args) => {
                return connectionFromArray(get(), args);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

in this case in query I can specify only (first, last, after, before) arguments, but what if I need to pass some additional arguments like userName etc. is that possible?

basically I need something like:

```
query {
    array (first: 1, userName: "name")
}
```

and in users type I can handle request like:

```
resolve: (root, args) => connectionFromArray(get(args.userName), args.args)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you just need to extend the relay helper `connectionArgs` with the new argument like this:

```
args: {
   ...connectionArgs,
   searchFor: { type: GraphQLString }
}
```

And then access it in the `resolve` function:

```
resolve: (root, args) => {
   // if the field argument 'searchFor' exists
   if (args.searchFor) {
   ...
   }
   ...
}
```